# need to understand eval in the code for ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code already exists in one of the javascript files i am working , may i know what does the following do

Its jquery ajax , i saw the response result and its a json string which is manually created by the backend.

I want to know what is eval doing here

```
success: function (response) {
 var response= response.replace(/\\/g, "%5C");
 eval(response); 
 },
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

Comment: can you post the result here?

Comment: @Benjammin' - please don't use w3school as reference. See http://w3fools.com

Comment: @benjammin , i know eval to some extent , but didn't understand why to do eval on the json response string.

Comment: Sorry, misinterpreted your question. Oded seems to have covered it well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) executes the passed in string as if it were javascript code.

What exactly happens depends entirely on the contents of `response`.

That is, the value of the `response` variable that is passed to the `eval` function gets evaluated as normal javascript.

If `response` was `"alert('Hello from evel!');"`, you would see an alert box with the text "Hello from evel!".

Comment: @Oded , can you explain it more if you have time, couldn't get clear picture

Comment: @oded, in the above scenario the response is json string, why do we need eval on that..??

Comment: @kobe - Probably so the returned json will be turned to Javascript objects that can then be used directly in other javascript.

Comment: @thanks very much got it now , the server ajax response is a plain string , i think this is converting into realy object

Comment: @kobe: Although you *can* use `eval` to convert a string in JSON notation into an object graph, it's a bad idea. Instead, use a proper JSON parser. There are three on Douglas Crockford's github page (one based on `eval` with some protections, the other two non-`eval`): https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/ Note also jQuery's built-in `jQuery.parseJSON`, but it just looks for a loaded JSON parser and uses it if it finds one, or falls back on `eval` (indirectly) if it doesn't find one.

Comment: @T.j crowder thanks for all the info , that was legacy code , but i changed backend to send proper wcf json endpoint , just for learning purposes i asked what that is doing.

Answer (score 2):

`eval()` executes a string as JavaScript code in the context of its execution context. Generally, this means scoped to whatever function it is in.

It is often used to evaluate a JSON string. Note that if you are `eval()`ing a JSON string, you should wrap it in parenthesis (`(` & `)`). The parenthesis means it will always be evaluated as an expression, not a block.